# Sybase Schema Model with mapped relations

Tags: sql, database, schema, sybase, sqlanywhere

I want to create schema model with mapped relations of Sybase database.

Database based on SQL Anywhere 9.

- What's the best method?
- Could I generate schema model "on the fly" based on database
  structure with some auto scan?
- Or I should create it manually?
- What software I should use, some dedicated by Sybase or some another
  tool?
- Once when I will create this schema model, how to easy keep it
  updated?

I need this schema model, to keep better documentation of the database, because actual database structure is very complicated and database is very very huge.

Comment: did u try DbVisualizer 8.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAP Sybase Power Designer is a good tool for visualizing, developing and maintaining databases.  It supports all the SAP Sybase databases, as well as other commercial RDMBS's (SQLServer, Teradata, DB2, etc).

[PowerDesigner](http://www54.sap.com/pc/tech/database/software/model-driven-architecture/index.html)